# Memory layout of C program (stack and heap)

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Is the stack and heap used common across the system or are the stack & heap created specifically for every process created?

Comment: Every process has their own private stack and heap.

Comment: More specifically, each process in Linux have their own privat memory map. That's why a pointer in one process can't generally be shared with another process, even if both are running the exact same program.

Comment: A process can even have multiple call stacks at the same time (See `makecontext(3)`, `sigaltstack(2)`, threads, etc.)

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer**: *yes*, every process has its own stack (that has to be
the case since each running entity has to have one) and heap.

**Long answer**: read on.

## Address Space

Every process owns an *address space*, part of which are stack and
heap. Code and global data (read-only, and read-write) are also
contained within that address space.

When I say, a process *owns* an address space, this means that one
process cannot peek inside another process's address space. This
*memory protection* is done in hardware, using a special device called
*memory management unit* (MMU) which is usually part of the CPU. One
can say that an address space is an abstraction of a hardware
implementation detail called MMU.

Said abstraction - address space - gives each process the perception
that it has available a linear array of bytes, numbered from 0 to
2^64-1 (on 64 bit systems). Contemporary systems are rarely equipped
with such an amount of memory, so generally only part of that address
space is backed by physical memory.

Whenever a process accesses memory that is not valid within its
address space, it is terminated: *it crashes*. An abstraction of
crashing (software people love abstractions) is receiving a signal -
`SIGSEGV` ("Segmentation violation") in the case of invalid memory
access.

## The /proc Filesystem

A special type of filesystem called `proc` is usually mounted on
`/proc`. To demonstrate address spaces and their layout, I start an
arbitrary program,

```
$ sleep 10000&
[1] 12010
```

Starting it in the background (`&`) gives me the process ID, which I
use to cd into the process's directory in `/proc`,

```
$ cd /proc/12010
```

Note that `/proc` is not a directory on disk, but rather something
that has a funny name (the process ID), looks like a directory, is a
directory, and has files and subdirectories that present to the user
the *attributes* of the process. Here, we are interested in the
*memory layout of the address space* - valid regions in the address
space.

This is what the `/proc/PID/maps file shows,

```
$ cat maps 
55b782825000-55b782827000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 1180965                    /usr/bin/sleep
55b782827000-55b78282b000 r-xp 00002000 fd:00 1180965                    /usr/bin/sleep
55b78282b000-55b78282d000 r--p 00006000 fd:00 1180965                    /usr/bin/sleep
55b78282e000-55b78282f000 r--p 00008000 fd:00 1180965                    /usr/bin/sleep
55b78282f000-55b782830000 rw-p 00009000 fd:00 1180965                    /usr/bin/sleep
55b783115000-55b783136000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7ff262d19000-7ff26fcfe000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 1188440                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7ff26fcfe000-7ff26fd23000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 1183177                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.30.so
7ff26fd23000-7ff26fe72000 r-xp 00025000 fd:00 1183177                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.30.so
7ff26fe72000-7ff26febc000 r--p 00174000 fd:00 1183177                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.30.so
7ff26febc000-7ff26febd000 ---p 001be000 fd:00 1183177                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.30.so
7ff26febd000-7ff26fec0000 r--p 001be000 fd:00 1183177                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.30.so
7ff26fec0000-7ff26fec3000 rw-p 001c1000 fd:00 1183177                    /usr/lib64/libc-2.30.so
7ff26fec3000-7ff26fec9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ff26feeb000-7ff26feed000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 1180257                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.30.so
7ff26feed000-7ff26ff0d000 r-xp 00002000 fd:00 1180257                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.30.so
7ff26ff0d000-7ff26ff15000 r--p 00022000 fd:00 1180257                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.30.so
7ff26ff16000-7ff26ff17000 r--p 0002a000 fd:00 1180257                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.30.so
7ff26ff17000-7ff26ff18000 rw-p 0002b000 fd:00 1180257                    /usr/lib64/ld-2.30.so
7ff26ff18000-7ff26ff19000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffffb0e8000-7ffffb10a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffffb1eb000-7ffffb1ee000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffffb1ee000-7ffffb1ef000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

This line for example

```
55b78282f000-55b782830000 rw-p 00009000 fd:00 1180965                    /usr/bin/sleep
```

is a *mapping* of the **r**ead-**w**ritable global data in the process,
populated from `/usr/bin/sleep` (at an offset in the file that is not
shown here).

Another mapping,

```
55b782827000-55b78282b000 r-xp 00002000 fd:00 1180965                    /usr/bin/sleep
```

is **r**eadable and e**x**ecutable - the *code*, which is populated from
the same binary. Other lines in the file show mappings taken from
shared libraries which contain comparable artifacts.

Finally, there are two mappings `stack` and `heap` that are not
populated from a file, but rather are anonymous allocations made by
the kernel when the process was created.